# Grouping the dataframe based on one variable

Tags: r, variables, grouping

I have a dataframe with 10 variables all of them numeric, and one of the variable name is age, I want  to group the observation based on age.example. age 17 to 18 one group, 19-22 another group and then each row should be attached to each group. And resulting should be a dataframe for further manipulations.
Model of the dataframe:

```
A   B   AGE
25  50  17
30  42  22
50  60  19
65  105 17
355 400 21
68  47  20
115 98  18
25  75  19
```

And I want result like

```
17-18 
A   B   AGE
25  50  17
65  105 17
115 98  18

19-22
A   B   AGE
30  42  22
50  60  19
355 400 21
68  47  20
115 98  18
25  75  19
```

I did group the dataset according to Age var using the split function, now my concern is how I could manipulate the grouped data. Eg:the answer looked like

```
$1

  A   B   AGE
  25  50  17
  65  105 17
  115 98  18

$2
A   B   AGE
    30  42  22
    50  60  19
    355 400 21
    68  47  20
    115 98  18
    25  75  19
```

My question is how can I access each group for further manipulation?
for eg: if I want to do t-test for each group separately?

Comment: You could try `cut` for grouping the age

Comment: I tried that, the Rstudio says it does not recognise!

Comment: Try `split(df1, cut(df1$AGE, breaks=c(16, 18, 22), labels=FALSE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach with `cut`

```
lst <- split(df1, cut(df1$AGE, breaks=c(16, 18, 22), labels=FALSE))
lst
# $`1`
#   A   B AGE
#1  25  50  17
#4  65 105  17
#7 115  98  18

#$`2`
#   A   B AGE
#2  30  42  22
#3  50  60  19
#5 355 400  21
#6  68  47  20
#8  25  75  19
```

#### Update

If you need to find the `sum`, `mean` of columns for each "list" element

```
lapply(lst, function(x) rbind(colSums(x[-3]),colMeans(x[-3])))
```

But, if the objective is to find the summary statistics based on the group, it can be done using any of the aggregating functions

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>% 
     group_by(grp=cut(AGE, breaks=c(16, 18, 22), labels=FALSE)) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(sum=sum(., na.rm=TRUE),
                      mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)), A:B)
 #   grp A_sum B_sum    A_mean    B_mean
 #1   1   205   253  68.33333  84.33333
 #2   2   528   624 105.60000 124.80000
```

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
 do.call(data.frame,
   aggregate(cbind(A,B)~cbind(grp=cut(AGE, breaks=c(16, 18, 22), 
    labels=FALSE)), df1, function(x) c(sum=sum(x), mean=mean(x))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(25L, 30L, 50L, 65L, 355L, 68L, 115L, 25L
), B = c(50L, 42L, 60L, 105L, 400L, 47L, 98L, 75L), AGE = c(17L, 
22L, 19L, 17L, 21L, 20L, 18L, 19L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "AGE"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: In case of this answer split(df1, cut(df1$AGE, breaks=c(16, 18, 22), labels=FALSE)) ages stops at 22.for me the right side should be open...so the first answer is prefered. the findInterval one....Thank you for u r time and effort.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you once again, I struggle to use the data! I mean how to use the split data? I want to find sum, average etc on the subset created!

Comment: @MerryKumar Please be specific.  Do you want to find the `sum`, `average` of columns or rows on both the subsets?

Comment: both the sum and average of all other variables except the age, as we grouped based on age on each group!

Comment: @MerryKumar Please do check it now

Comment: y %>%
+      group_by(grp =cut(age, breaks =c(14,18,23,30,65), labels =FALSE)) %>% 
+        summarise_each(funs(mean),bwt)
Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

  grp      bwt
1   1 2934.938
2   2 2949.000
3   3 2871.339
4   4 3167.800
5  NA 2967.333

Comment: @MerryKumar Sorry, I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: @MerryKumar I updated the function now with `na.rm=TRUE`

Comment: I tried with one var and just the mean to understand it, and I got the output, but fifth group name is showing N.A and also how to include all the  ages after 30 too...unlimited ie open ended at the right side!

Comment: @MerryKumar If the fifth grouping is showing NA, then there may not be any non-NA values in it.  Please check your dataset for that.  If you need to specify after 30 ages, perhaps `cut(AGE, breaks=c(16, 18, 22, 30, Inf), labels=FALSE)`

Comment: grp      bwt
1   1 2934.938
2   2 2949.000
3   3 2871.339
4   4 3167.800
5  NA 2967.333 this is the output and the fith group number is showing N.A!

Comment: @MerryKumar Is it the same data?  If not, please update the data in your post and the expected output

Comment: May I ask one more question if I have to find correlation between  A & B var after the dataset is grouped by age var. we have grouped the dataset by age and done the summary stats also, but if I have to find the correlation then what shall I do?

Comment: @MerryKumar Please check `?cor`.  I guess `df1 %>% 
     group_by(grp=cut(AGE, breaks=c(16, 18, 22), labels=FALSE)) %>% summarise(Cor=cor(A,B))`

Comment: How can access each element of the grouped item? i mean in $`1`
#   A   B AGE
#1  25  50  17
#4  65 105  17
#7 115  98  18
 this  how can access  25?

Comment: My question to make it more clear, how can I manipulate the grouped data, groupwise!  If I want to find cor , or do anova test on each group how can I do that?it the data set is bigger!

Comment: @MerryKumar I did the `cor` group wise.  It doesn't make sense to do `cor` for one element wrt to another.  If you look at the documentation `?cor`, `x: a numeric vector, matrix or data frame.`.  If this doesn't help, please do post as a new question.  It is difficult to understand from the comments.

Comment: Ok then I am posting as new question!! I have many regarding this. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The split function will work with dataframes. Use either `cut` with 'breaks' or `findInterval` with an appropriate set of cutpoints (named 'vec' if you are using named parameters) as the criterion for grouping, the second argument to `split`. The default for `cut` is intervals closed on the right and default for `findInterval` is closed on the left.

```
> split(dat, findInterval(dat$AGE, c(17, 19.5, 22.5)))
$`1`
    A   B AGE
1  25  50  17
3  50  60  19
4  65 105  17
7 115  98  18
8  25  75  19

$`2`
    A   B AGE
2  30  42  22
5 355 400  21
6  68  47  20
```